# How to determine what covalent compound a substance is?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

I have been given a substance which is unknown in my class. The substance is white in colour and is in a powder form. I have conducted a few tests and have found out that the substance is a covalent compound.

Properties of the substance

- Has a low melting point. When the item was melting it left a yellow/orange colour liquid, later it hardened and retained the same yellow/orange colour.
- Soluble in water
- Does not conduct electricity in solid state
- Does not conduct electricity when dissolved in water
- pH of 3-4
- Soluble in Ethanol
- Is not a sugar, used bennedict's solution and did not turn red instead gave of vapour and started bubbling.

From these steps I have concluded that the substance is a covalent compound. However, I need to find exactly what type of elements is in the covalent compound. If you could suggest a test to conduct to figure out what type of elements there are, it would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the aqueous solution of it acidic, alkaline or neutral?

Comment: I have not tested the PH level yet but if that helps, I will try it out. If the aqueous is acidic then the substance will be acidic, am I correct?

Comment: Is  it soluble in ethanol ? in an alcane like gasoline, cyclohexane, petroleum ?

Comment: I have only tested the solubility in Water, if ethanol helps, I will try that out too.

Comment: Also how would ethanol help in this situation?

Comment: I am sure that if this is a class exercise there must be the way to figure out what the sample is. But, as formulated, this question can be answered by a full course in analytical chemistry. Surely not in few lines. Perhaps someone here can guess it (a common exercise, luck, etc) but this indeed requires at least an introduction to organic analysis.Moreover, *note that title and text ask for different things*.

Comment: What is your teacher doing? Before asking questions, or giving out such complicated tasks? Sounds like he wasn't teaching anything.

Comment: @Karl Depending on the hidden background, it may be the opposite. The teacher can make advanced students to solve non trivial questions what need a lot of effort to solve it, and the solution may not be even reached. Such students can learn a lot from it.

Comment: @Poutnik Yea. Doing that with not so advanced students is however known to be completely counterproductive. Which seems to be the case here, imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is huge, because there exist many millions of different compounds which are white, soluble in water, and do not conduct electricity. Here are a couple of preliminary tests.

You might first determine if it is organic, by heating it in a test tube in a Bunsen burner. It will darken and be progressively transformed into charcoal if it is organic.
Is  it soluble in ethanol ? Is it soluble in an alcane like gasoline, cyclohexane, petroleum ?

Does it react with a diluted solution of CuSO4 ? If it produces a deeper blue color, it is probably some amine like RNH2, or a complexant agent like tartaric acid. If it produces a colored precipitate (blue or green), it may be a basic substance or a carboxylic salt.

Does it discolor Bromine water ? If yes, it probably contains a double bond C=C.

Does it react with Fehling's reactant (solution of CuSO4 plus much sodium tartrate and a few NaOH) ? If it does make an orange or brown precipitate at boiling temperature, it is a reducing sugar.

Does it react with diluted solution of permanganate KMnO4 ? Try in acidic and in basic solution. If so there is a reducing agent, and further study must be done.

Does it react with Tollens' reagent (solution of silver nitrate plus ammonia) producing a silver mirror at boiling temperature ? If yes, it is an aldehyde.

Knowing if the substance contains nitrogen is a little bit more difficult, as you should do Lassaigne test : heat it with a little bit metallic sodium in a test tube to high temperature, then dissolving into water with iron compounds. This a bit more dangerous : It requires some skill

There are plenty of other tests that could be made. Solving this problem in a general way would take hours. It is nearly impossible to solve it now. Try to find a treatise of organic qualitative analysis.

Comment: My substance is soluble in ethanol, does this mean its organic?

Comment: Also, I have burnt the compound in a test tube in a bunsen burner yet the substance is not darkening and it dissolves in Ethanol. When it was burning it also released gas whihc could be smoke or vapor.

Comment: Does it react with solutions of CuSO4, or with AgNO3, or with KMnO4 ? Try ! Does it color the flame ?